# how to limit the jquery search scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

It looks like `JQuery` does the search in the current `document` when using a selector.

How to search for an element only inside a `div` element?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

jQuery selectors work very much like CSS selectors, which you may be more familiar with.

First, select the div, and then descend from that:

```
$('#my-div').find('some-selector').
```

or build your selector to match children of the element in question:

```
$('#my-div some-selector')
```

Comment: (the first one being faster)

Comment: @Amadan. Why are you so sure?

Comment: @gdoron: There was an article about it. jQuery is optimised to look up the ID-only selectors with minimum fuss, straight to `getDocumentById`. Anything else gets passed to Sizzle. Unless the browser has `querySelector` - and in some cases IIRC it was shown Sizzle even outperformed `querySelector`. Actually, I did a quick google now, and there's many articles about it; [here's one of them](http://engineeredweb.com/blog/10/12/3-tips-make-your-jquery-selectors-faster/).

Answer (score 17):

Old question, but everyone seems to have missed the *scoped* jQuery selector (using the scope you desired, i.e. your div selector, as the second parameter)

e.g. use

```
var $matches = $('.adiv', '#mydiv');
```

This is a shorter equivalent of:

```
var $matches = $('#mydiv').find('.adiv');
```

Answer (score 8):

```
var elems = jQuery(".foo", jQuery("#divYourWantToLimitTo") );  //BAD
//or
var elems = jQuery("#divYourWantToLimitTo .foo");  //Better
//or
var elems = jQuery("#divYourWantToLimitTo").find(".foo");  //BEST
```

Comment: The first option is wrong, jQuery doesn't except a string-selector as a context. check the docs.

Comment: @gdoron - Could you please explain that, as it seems to me it would be turned into exactly the same as the third option internally ?? I do realise the docs says "A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context" etc... but it does seem to work just fine ??

Comment: @epascarello - I see that, just wondered why, as I use it the way it was all the time, and always figured it was ok ?

Comment: @epascarello why is the first option bad? And wouldn't it be better to implement it as jQuery(".foo", "#divYourWantToLimitTo"), since from [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) it is internally implemented as your best option i.e. $('#divYourWantToLimitTo').find('.foo')?

Comment: The reason why find is better is because it tends to be the fastest option. http://jsperf.com/perf-of-finding-elems But since this was posted 2 years ago, newer versions of jQuery, the context selector is faster than the selector.

Comment: The first and third methods are identical. The [jquery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context) say: *Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method, so  $( "span", this ) is equivalent to  $( this ).find( "span" ).*

Answer (score 2):

jQuery provides several ways to search for specific elements:

```
$("#your_div").find(".your_things");        //Find everything inside
  //-or-
$("#your_div").filter(".your_things");      //Find only the top level
  //-or-
$("#your_div .your_things");                //Easiest
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var elements = $('div ' + yourSearch);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div-selector').find('the selector-you-are-looking-for');
```