# How to write jquery selectors for dynamically generated html elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, jquery-selectors

I'm currently writing an object oriented module which assigns callback to dynamically generated elements.

```
function Instant(containerID) {
    this.var1 = 0;
    this.var2 = 0;
    this.containerID = containerID;
    // and more variables...
};
```

And here `containerID` is the id of a `DIV` which is *dynamically* generated. I populate this `DIV` via Ajax Request which reads a file like the following:

```
<!-- content.html -->
<div class="general_container">
    <div class="top_container">
        <!-- plenty of divs, spans etc -->
    </div>

    <div class="tweet_section">
        <!-- plenty of divs, spans etc -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the important part is, I assign all callbacks like the following:

```
Instant.prototype.addCallbacks = function() {
    $(this.containerID + " bar").click(function() {
        $(this.containerID + " bar").foo();
    });

    $(this.containerID + " bar").click(function() {
        $(this.containerID + " bar").foo();
    });

    $(this.containerID+ " bar").click(function(e) {
        $(this.containerID + "bar, " + this.containerID+ " bar").foo();
    });
});
```

As you see, I always have to put `this.containerID` before each selector to assign events. (Therefore, I make sure I'm selecting only one element)  Now, my code is full of clutter as I have plenty of `this.containerID`s. I don't know if there is a smarter method to make my code easy. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is a sample [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CZg4T/1/).

Note that this is not my real module, I just made it up to make it clear!

Answer (score 1):

Then you shouldn't be using IDs. You should be using classes instead.

[It would take long to edit your code](http://jsfiddle.net/CZg4T/3/), but here's a hint: Add a handler to the parent. Use event delegation, like `.on()`. Then have it listen for all children, now or future.

Comment: Did you check the jsfiddle example? If I use classes, I need to use something like `$('.className:eq(' + number +')' + " bar").click(...)` . So this means I always have to use a selector.

Comment: @CihadTurhan that's where delegation comes in. the handlers don't get attached for each unit added. they are attached to a parent container. it's like a generic handler applicable to all targets.

Comment: you're right. I know what `.on()` does as well. But it's logic is not ideal here because each container is managed by the different instances of my class. I'm not sure if I tell it in the right way. Sorry, this is not my main language.

Comment: Use parent element that is visible on loading and attach event throught parent $('parent').on('click', 'element', function(){})

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate java script file and put your add callbacks function in there and just pass the containerID. That way, you can re-use it later. However, looks like you cannot get rid of containterID since you will be needing that to do your add, subtract, save etc..

in your current file shown as above,

```
Instant.prototype.addCallbacks = createAddCallbacks(this.ContainerID);
```

create addCallbacks.js

```
function createAddCallbacks(containerId)
{
Instant.prototype.addCallbacks = function() {
    $(containerId + " bar").click(function() {
        $(containerId + " bar").foo();
    });

    $(containerId + " bar").click(function() {
        $(containerId + " bar").foo();
    });

    $(containerId+ " bar").click(function(e) {
        $(containerId + "bar, " + containerIdD+ " bar").foo();
    });
});
}
```

Comment: Well, most probably I will do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I find a better method according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543897/how-to-limit-the-jquery-search-scope) 
I wanted to limit the scope of my selector.

Firstly, I'll create a jQuery instance variable

```
function Instant(containerID) {
    this.var1 = 0;
    this.var2 = 0;
    this.container= $('#'+containerID);
    // and more variables...
};
```

and adding a new prototype like this

```
Instant.prototype.$ = function(selector){
    return this.container.find(selector);
};
```

I'll only use `this.$(selector)` function which is better.

Answer (score 0):

Like @JosephTheDreamer said, use [Event Delegation](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2010/03/4/event-delegation-with-jquery). ([`Jquery.fn.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data))
Using event delegation you set one handler to multiple targets. It means just one handler in memory and dynamic event handlers set.

[I made a demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandosavio/XavuK/5/) modifying your code, take a look...

```
Instant.prototype.addCallbacks = function () {
    var selfContainer = null, // DOMElement container
        me = this; // Object reference

    $('body').on("click", ".selection_container .btn-add", function () { //Using event delegation
        selfContainer = $(this).parents(".general_container"); //set DOMElement
        selfContainer.find("input[name=currentValue]").val(++me.instantValue);
    });

    $('body').on("click", ".selection_container .btn-subtract", function () {
        selfContainer.find("input[name=currentValue]").val(--me.instantValue);
    });

   $('body').on("click", ".selection_container .btn-reset", function () {
        me.instantValue = 0;
        selfContainer.find('input[name=currentValue]').val(0);
    });

    $('body').on("click", ".selection_container .btn-save", function () {
        me.savedValue = me.instantValue;
    });

    $('body').on("click", ".selection_container .btn-load", function () {
        me.instantValue = me.savedValue;
        selfContainer.find('input[name=currentValue]').val(me.savedValue);
    });
};
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: I already have a demo :) also, every call to the `addCallbacks` in your code would add set upon set of delegated handlers. try adding 3 to a first unit, and add 3 on the second unit, the results *will* add from the previous unit - not the intended behavior. Thus, adding the delegated handlers **only once** is enough.