# Limit to objects within a div when using .each() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to iterate over all `div`s of a single class on a page. I have something similar to the following:

```
$(.person).each(function(i,obj){
    var name = $(".person .name").val();
}
```

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543897/how-to-limit-the-jquery-search-scope) question. Is this a good way to get the name from an `input` from a specific div when iterating?

```
<div class="person">
    Name:<input type="text" class="name">
</div>
```

There are many person `div` on a page

Comment: show us some HTML code

Comment: *"Is this a good way to get the name from an input from a specific div when iterating"* no, because that will get the value of the first one found. (and it's riddled with syntax errors)

Comment: It's the same global variable and same selector for each iteration, so no, it's not a good way to get anything really

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$('.person').each(function(){
    var name = $(this).find(".name").val();
});
```

Inside the `.each` callback, `this` refers to currently iterated DOM element. By passing it to jQuery (`$(this)`), you create a selection of one element. `.find` then searches for descendants matching the selector inside that element.

Comment: what is the scope of `this` in the context of an each()? I am new to javascript and come from strongly typed OO languages

Comment: Small remark: no need to add the parameters if you only need `this`. Otherwise use `$(obj)` in your "unedited" example ^^

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot: Already updated my answer. You can also have a look at the documentation, it's explained there: http://api.jquery.com/each/. *"More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword `this` refers to the element."* For more general info about `this`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this. Understanding how `this` works is indeed very important.

Comment: fyi your second link in your comment is dead

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot: I don't know, sometimes Stack Overflow breaks the links I paste (or I'm doing something wrong). Same link, and it works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(.person).each(function(i,obj){
    name = $(this).find(".name").val(); //$(this) will represent current div
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.person').each(function(){
    name = $(this).find('.name').val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there can be more than one `input.name` you need to use an array:

```
var names = [];

names = $(".person .name").map(function(i,e){
   return $(e).val();
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/58TQ6/1/

If there is only one name field on the form, put an id on the `input` instead of a class.

```
<input id="name" type="text"/>

var name = $("#name").val();
```