# How to disable specific input fields on focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `GridView` that renders a table. This table has text fields and input fields.

I wrote the following `jQuery` to disable text fields on focus. It works fine:

```
$(function(){

    $('input[type="text"]').live("focus", function() {
        var rowId = $(this).attr('id');
        var inputField = $(this).attr('name');
        alert(inputField.indexOf('txtSearchValue'));
        $('tr').each(function(){
            var inputId = $(this).find('input[type="text"]').attr('id');
            var submitId = $(this).closest("tr").find('input[type="submit"]').attr('id');
            if(inputId != null && typeof inputId !== "undefined"){
                if(rowId !== inputId){               
                    $(this).find('input[type="text"]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    $(this).closest("tr").find('input[type="submit"]').attr("disabled","disabled");
                }
            }
        });                                
    });
});
```

I also have another text field that is not a part of a generated table but it also gets disabled every time I click on textfields belonging to the table.

This is a text field:

```
<input id="ctl00_ContentMain_txtSearchValue" type="text" value="2222" name="ctl00$ContentMain$txtSearchValue"></input>
```

I'm trying to use:

`var inputField = $(this).attr('name');
 inputField.indexOf('txtSearchValue');`

to access that extra field, but I'm not sure how to combine it with my `jQuery` to make sure it is always enabled.

Any ideas?

How can I modify it, so, the extra field

This is my html table:

```
<TABLE style="POSITION: absolute; BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: red; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: red; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: red; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: red; TOP: 150px" id=ctl00_ContentMain_grvIsoSearchResults class=DataWebControlStyle border=1 rules=all cellSpacing=0>
<TBODY>
<TR class=HeaderStyle>
<TH scope=col>ISONUM</TH>
<TH scope=col>OFFICE NAME</TH>
<TH scope=col>REGION</TH>
<TH scope=col>DIVISION</TH>
<TH scope=col>EMAIL ADDRESS</TH></TR>
<TR class=RowStyle>
    <TD><SPAN style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 70px; DISPLAY: inline-block"  id=ctl00_ContentMain_grvIsoSearchResults_ctl02_txtgvIsoNum>222222222 </SPAN>
    </TD>
     <TD><SPAN style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 200px; DISPLAY: inline-block" id=ctl00_ContentMain_grvIsoSearchResults_ctl02_txtgvIsoOfficeName>Test, Eugene Test </SPAN>
     </TD>
     <TD><SPAN style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 50px; DISPLAY: inline-block" id=ctl00_ContentMain_grvIsoSearchResults_ctl02_txtgvRegion>99</SPAN> 
     </TD>
      <TD><SPAN style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 50px; DISPLAY: inline-block" id=ctl00_ContentMain_grvIsoSearchResults_ctl02_txtgvDivision>11111</SPAN> 
      </TD>
      <TD><INPUT id=ctl00_ContentMain_grvIsoSearchResults_ctl02_txtgvEmailAddress class=textInput name=ctl00$ContentMain$grvIsoSearchResults$ctl02$txtgvEmailAddress value=test@test.com> 
          <INPUT id=ctl00_ContentMain_grvIsoSearchResults_ctl02_btnEmailUpdate onclick="return ValidateEmail(this);" name=ctl00$ContentMain$grvIsoSearchResults$ctl02$btnEmailUpdate value=Update type=submit> 
      </TD>
      </TR>
      <TR class=AlternatingRowStyle>
      <TD><SPAN style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 70px; DISPLAY: inline-block" id=ctl00_ContentMain_grvIsoSearchResults_ctl03_txtgvIsoNum>CB2222001 </SPAN>
      </TD>
       <TD><SPAN style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 200px; DISPLAY: inline-block" id=ctl00_ContentMain_grvIsoSearchResults_ctl03_txtgvIsoOfficeName>DENNIS PETROVIC </SPAN>
      </TD>
      <TD><SPAN style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 50px; DISPLAY: inline-block" id=ctl00_ContentMain_grvIsoSearchResults_ctl03_txtgvRegion></SPAN>
      </TD>
      <TD><SPAN style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 50px; DISPLAY: inline-block" id=ctl00_ContentMain_grvIsoSearchResults_ctl03_txtgvDivision>99801</SPAN> 
      </TD>
       <TD>
         <INPUT id=ctl00_ContentMain_grvIsoSearchResults_ctl03_txtgvEmailAddress class=textInput name=ctl00$ContentMain$grvIsoSearchResults$ctl03$txtgvEmailAddress value=dennis@dlgent.com> 
          <INPUT id=ctl00_ContentMain_grvIsoSearchResults_ctl03_btnEmailUpdate onclick="return ValidateEmail(this);" name=ctl00$ContentMain$grvIsoSearchResults$ctl03$btnEmailUpdate value=Update type=submit>
       </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR class=RowStyle>
        <TD><SPAN style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 70px; DISPLAY: inline-block" id=ctl00_ContentMain_grvIsoSearchResults_ctl04_txtgvIsoNum>FT2222001 </SPAN>
       </TD>
        <TD><SPAN style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 200px; DISPLAY: inline-block" id=ctl00_ContentMain_grvIsoSearchResults_ctl04_txtgvIsoOfficeName>DENNIS PETROVIC </SPAN>
       </TD>
        <TD><SPAN style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 50px; DISPLAY: inline-block" id=ctl00_ContentMain_grvIsoSearchResults_ctl04_txtgvRegion></SPAN>
        </TD>
        <TD><SPAN style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 50px; DISPLAY: inline-block" id=ctl00_ContentMain_grvIsoSearchResults_ctl04_txtgvDivision>99801</SPAN> 
       </TD>
       <TD><INPUT id=ctl00_ContentMain_grvIsoSearchResults_ctl04_txtgvEmailAddress class=textInput name=ctl00$ContentMain$grvIsoSearchResults$ctl04$txtgvEmailAddress value=dennis@dlgent.com> 
       <INPUT id=ctl00_ContentMain_grvIsoSearchResults_ctl04_btnEmailUpdate onclick="return ValidateEmail(this);" name=ctl00$ContentMain$grvIsoSearchResults$ctl04$btnEmailUpdate value=Update type=submit> 
        </TD>
     </TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: If you find my answer useful please accept it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You attach a function to all `'input[type="text"]'`. This means that all the input fields on your page will have this function. You might want to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543897/how-to-limit-the-jquery-search-scope) question.

Your query should looks something like this: `table > input[type="text"]`. [For more details](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/).

**UPDATE**

Looking at your code I am not sure your system does what you really want. Anyway, here is a [filldle](http://jsfiddle.net/E38Ut/6/) that gives you the fields with `inputText` classes from your table. Then you can attach to them a function (Just pop up the console -- in Chrome F12 and you'll see the selected elements of the page).

As I said you need to restrict your selector level by level:

```
$('td > .textInput').each(function(){
    console.log(this);
})
```

So you select all the `.textInput` classes from all `td` tags. This will work without just uwing `$('.textInput')` in case you don't have any other `td` tags. If you have multiple tables use the id of the table you want to use in the selector then descend from there to the required level.

Comment: Can I use `not` filter when I attach `focus` event to my input? Something like ` $('input[type="text"]').not("[name='value']").live...

Comment: Well... you have the code so just try it. But ideally you would restrict the selectors with the "Child Selector".

Comment: Tell you the truth, I'm really new to jQuery and somethimes it is difficult to understand what exactly I need to do to make some things work for me...:) Thank you

Comment: Can you add the `html` for your table?